# Word VSTO - Selecting two floating shapes using CTRL, causes Selection object to also contain the inline shape that was not selected

Tags: ms-word, vsto

1. Open a new Word O365 document using desktop application
2. Press enter a few(8-10) times
3. Position the cursor at about 5th line and Insert an icon
4. Insert two shapes - one above and one below such that the icon lies in between the anchor of two shapes.(See screenshot)
5. Select both shapes together using Ctrl

[image][image]

In the following VSTO code,

```
Selection selection = app.ActiveWindow.Selection;
InlineShapes inShapes = selection.InlineShapes;
ShapeRange shapes = selection.ShapeRange;
```

I expect inShapes to contain nothing, but **it contains the black icon object that was not even selected**. The selection types comes out as "WdSelectionType.wdSelectionShape"

[image: Add]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then selecting a floating shape, actually selects it's anchor range. It's that anchor range is at the same position as the online shape then that would be in the selection too.

Comment: Why are you selecting anything? Working with selections is very inefficient.

Comment: In the Selection Pane under Layout tab, I see that only the floating shapes are selected when I select both floating shapes together. The inline shape is not selected. So somehow, Word knows to do that correctly. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @macropod: I intend to manipulate properties like fill of shapes/icons, when the object is selected and a plugin button is clicked. If not selections, what should I use?

Comment: Use the Range object instead. That's almost always faster and more reliable.

Comment: @John: I'm only interested in selected shapes/icons in Word at any given point during the plugin. I want to manipulate the color/glow effects of selected objects on the Word application when a button of my plugin/add-in is clicked. Using Range instead of Selection maybe faster, but I don't see how that'll help me resolve my problem. Can you advise on how to get only the shapes from what is selected on Word?